# How do I see debug log in local App Engine instance

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

AppEngine tutorial 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps.html
suggests that the debug logs generated by java.util.logging.Logger can be seen at admin console.

However I don't see the log information from admin console for local instance at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin

Is there a way to see debug log when developing locally?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I see them appearing in the terminal where I start the development server.

Comment: I saw debug log in Eclipse console now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set:

```
.level = ALL
```

In your logging.properties file. See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Logging for info on how to set up this file.

Comment: Aha, I misunderstood your question -- I thought you were asking specifically about debug level logging. You were asking about the logging output in general.